# Regex replace a certain word with optional commas and space around it

Tags: regex, sed

I have a python code that for example could look like that

```
class Foo(Bar, Baz, Jazz):
   pass
```

or that

```
class Foo(Baz, Bar, Jazz):
   pass

class Foo(Baz, Jazz, Bar):
   pass
```

What I need is to remove `Bar` with from the list of parents in inheritance hierarchy.

So the idea is to remove occurencies of `Bar` with optional `,` to the left or (exclusive) to right to it.

My attempt to do that with sed.

```
echo 'class Foo(Baz, Bar, Jazz):' | sed -r 's/(class .*\(.*)([, ]*Bar[, ]*)/\1/'
```

gives correct result

```
class Foo(Baz, Jazz):
```

Comment: If it's a correct result, then what's the problem?

Comment: Remove `Python` tag, this question has nothing to do with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then this `sed` should do what you expect.

```
sed -r '/^\s*class.*:\s*$/s/(,\s*Bar\s*|\s*Bar\s*,\s*)//g' file
```

Output:

```
class Foo(Baz, Jazz):
   pass

class Foo(Baz, Jazz):
   pass
```

Comment: Of course not, because there are imports in the file so it should work only in the context of a class.

Comment: Okay, this time it doesn't removes Bar in ```class Foo(Bar, Baz, Jazz)```

Answer (score 0):

```
(class .*?\(.*?)(?:[\s,]+Bar\s*|\s*Bar[\s,]+)
```

You can use this.Replace by `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zJ7vZ4/2

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(class .*?\(.*?)(?:[\s,]+Bar\s*|\s*Bar[\s,]+)')
test_str = u"class Foo(Bar, Baz, Jazz):\n   pass\n\n\n\nclass Foo(Baz, Bar, Jazz):\n   pass\n\nclass Foo(Baz, Jazz, Bar):\n   pass"
subst = u"\1"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: ```class Foo(Baz, Jazz,):``` - this left trailing comma in last example. Don't like that =)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple expressions to satisfy different conditions like this:

```
$ cat a.py 
class Foo(Baz, Bar, Jazz):
   pass

class Foo(Baz, Jazz, Bar):
   pass

class Foo(Bar, Baz, Jazz):
   pass
$ sed -r -e '/^\s*class.*,\s*Bar\s*,.*$/s/,\s*Bar\s*,/,/g' -e '/^\s*class.*,\s*Bar\s*\).*$/s/,\s*Bar\s*\)/)/g' -e '/^\s*class.*\(\s*Bar\s*,\s*.*$/s/\(\s*Bar\s*,\s*/(/g' a.py 
class Foo(Baz, Jazz):
   pass

class Foo(Baz, Jazz):
   pass

class Foo(Baz, Jazz):
   pass
$
```

The regex also has checks that it should perform substitution on lines that satisfy `class` declaration in python, therefore it doesn't touches any other lines(for eg: leaves `import` as it is).